# Building CUDA 9 application from Visual Studio 2017

Tags: cuda, visual-studio-2017

I've recently installed the Cuda Toolkit v9, and have been attempting to run through some sample projects in Visual Studio 2017 in order to validate the setup, but can't seem to get the Cuda applications to build via Visual Studio. The "CUDA Installation Guide for Microsoft Windows" suggests running two applications; deviceQuery and then bandwidthTest. The deviceQuery application runs ok, but bandwidthTest (and all of the other sample applications that i have tried all seem to fail with the same error (exited with code 2), which is unfortunately not very descriptive. An example can be found below. Any suggestions?

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\BuildCustomizations\CUDA 9.0.targets(707,9): error MSB3721: The command ""C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.0\bin\nvcc.exe" -gencode=arch=compute_30,code=\"sm_30,compute_30\" -gencode=arch=compute_35,code=\"sm_35,compute_35\" -gencode=arch=compute_37,code=\"sm_37,compute_37\" -gencode=arch=compute_50,code=\"sm_50,compute_50\" -gencode=arch=compute_52,code=\"sm_52,compute_52\" -gencode=arch=compute_60,code=\"sm_60,compute_60\" -gencode=arch=compute_70,code=\"sm_70,compute_70\" --use-local-env --cl-version 2017 -ccbin "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\bin\HostX86\x64" -x cu  -I./ -I../../common/inc -I./ -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.0/include" -I../../common/inc -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.0\include"  -G   --keep-dir x64\Debug -maxrregcount=0  --machine 64 --compile -cudart static -Xcompiler "/wd 4819" -g   -DWIN32 -DWIN32 -D_MBCS -D_MBCS -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W3 /nologo /Od /FS /Zi /RTC1 /MTd " -o x64/Debug/bandwidthTest.cu.obj "C:\ProgramData\NVIDIA Corporation\CUDA Samples\v9.0\1_Utilities\bandwidthTest\bandwidthTest.cu"" **exited with code 2**.

Comment: turn up the verbosity on VS.  Then you will get an actual useful error message from `nvcc` in addition to what you have now.

Comment: Not quite sure what the problem was, but after leaving my computer over night the application is now compiling and runs ok. Closing this case.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure what the problem was, but after leaving my computer over night the application is now compiling and runs ok. Closing this case